# How to apply "wrap when typing reaches right margin" in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I set "wrap when typing reaches right margin" in `Cody Style` -> `General` preferences and defined a new margin, how to apply this new settings to files so they were reformatted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Very easy:

- select the root of your module in project view
- in the code menu select "Reformat..."

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention this important detail:

IDE Settings > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and braces > Ensure right margin is not exceeded

must be checked. (at least to reformat java files, same checkbox for other files exists)

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ 14 you can set the right margin on a per-language basis by going to

> IDE Settings > Code Style > $LANGUAGE > Wrapping and braces > Right margin (columns):

And setting a new value.